# Query a custom object's "__Share" in subquery

Tags: soql, apex-sharing

Is it possible to use a subquery to obtain a list of that object's __Share's?

For example:
ObjA has been manually shared via apex. At some point I may want to query information about ObjA and get a list of its shares. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
[Select 
    Id,
    Name,
   (Select Id, UserOrGroupdID FROM ObjA__Shares) 
From 
    ObjA__c Where Id = :someId];
```

From my testing in the dev console, it doesn't not appear to be the case. For the record I've tried ObjA__Share and ObjA__Shares to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is perfectly possible. You are just using the wrong syntax.

This will work:

```
SELECT ID, Name, (SELECT ID, UserOrGroupdID FROM Shares) FROM ObjA__c WHERE ID = :someId;
```

In order to find the right child relationship names, I always use the Schema Explorer in Eclipse. By browsing to an object and then selecting 'Child Relationships' you can find out the 'Relationship Name' of the child relationship.

Comment: Thanks! That'll do nicely. I'm not an Eclipse user but that's darn good to know. I'd vote you up but I don't quite have enough rep yet!